# Was bedeutet „nichts wie hinterher“?

Tags: meaning, phrase, idiom

Was bedeutet die Phrase

> nichts wie hinterher?

Oft trifft man diese zum Beispiel im Kontext von Reisen. Jedoch kann ich die Bedeutung nicht klar verstehen, auch nicht mit Hilfe von Google.

Comment: Your actual question I guess is what's the meaning of "nichts wie". You can say "nichts wie weg", "nichts wie los", "nichts wie hin", "nicht wie raus".

Comment: *nichts wie hinterher* can be written longer as: *nichts ist so wichtig wie hinterher zu laufen*

Answer (score 9):

Die Phrase *nichts wie* kann fast wörtlich verstanden werden: Ich muss jetzt etwas tun, und soll mich auf nichts anderes konzentrieren.

> In zwei Minuten fährt die Tram! Nichts wie hin! (sonst ist sie weg)
>
> Der Kerl hat die Kasse ausgeraubt! Nichts wie hinterher! (und ihn einfangen)
>
> Es brennt, und gleich erreicht das Feuer den Öltank! Nichts wie raus! (sonst werden wir von der Explosion erwischt)

Man könnte sie »ausformuliert« denken als »denk an **nichts** so sehr **wie** an […]«, aber erstens würde das niemand so sagen, und zweitens trifft das auch nur haarscharf den Kern.

---

Eng verwandt ist die Phrase *nichts als*, die allerdings eine andere Nuance hat: Einem begegnet gerade **nichts** anderes **als** das, was man nicht haben möchte.

> Nichts als Probleme mit dem neuen Windows. (Unter Linux wäre das nicht passiert.)
>
> Nichts als Schwachsinn machen die Studenten. (Man muss sie ständig beaufsichtigen.)
>
> Fragen, Fragen, nichts als Fragen. (Dabei will ich endlich Feierabend machen.)

Comment: "nichts wie weg" == **nicht** erst den Zündschlüssel entfernen, sondern *sofort* abspringen, sonst werden wir...